# Already using utf8mb4 but getting 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81\xF0\x9F...'

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, encoding, character-encoding

All answers to the issue "Incorrect string value" point to using utf8mb4. However, I'm still using that I still get that error.

Running

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name, collation_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "test"
  AND T.table_name = "products";
```

produces

```
character_set_name  collation_name
utf8mb4             utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

And running

```
SELECT character_set_name, collation_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE table_schema = "test"
  AND table_name = "products"
  AND column_name = "description";
```

produces the same result. Then, when I try to update the column `description`:
UPDATE `test`.`products` SET `description`='Esperienza molto negativa... SCONSIGLIATISSIMO' WHERE `id`='50'

I get the abovementioned error

```
1366: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x81\xF0\x9F...' for column 'description' at row 1
```

I've tried this update both through a jdbc connection `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=yes;characterEncoding=utf8;` and directly through MySQLWorkbench. I don't know what else to try of look for. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manufacturerId_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_fk` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TEST',
  `ownerId_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating_fk` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorName` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `authorUrl` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `manufacturer_authorUrl_UNIQUE` (`manufacturerId_fk`,`authorUrl`),
  KEY `fk_products_manufacturers_idx` (`manufacturerId_fk`),
  KEY `fk_products_users_idx` (`ownerId_fk`),
  KEY `fk_products_validRatings_idx` (`rating_fk`),
  KEY `fk_products_productTypes` (`type_fk`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_productTypes` FOREIGN KEY (`type_fk`) REFERENCES `productTypes` (`type`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_manufacturers` FOREIGN KEY (`manufacturerId_fk`) REFERENCES `manufacturers` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_products_validRatings` FOREIGN KEY (`rating_fk`) REFERENCES `validRatings` (`value`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=418 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: This is because of character set mismatch for sure, as a try you can recreate the table and insert some sample data and then try to update again.

Comment: @AdarshGangadharan I've just tried dropping and recreating the table, then inserting a row and updating it. Same result

Comment: what is the full hex sequence? it seams there is an error in it...

Comment: @PavelGatnar I don't think there is anything wrong with the hex sequence. It's just for times the hex for GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES, \xF0\x9F\x98\x81

Comment: Do you have any trigger on it? Please provide the show create table results.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table in question.  And provide the JDBC connection string.

Comment: @RickJames Added `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. The JDBC connection string is right above it

Answer (score 1):

A similar question occurred to me with a text field.
**(MySQL 1366 error incorrect string value)**

I confirmed the database, table, column character set were all `utf8mb4`.

The problem was solved by changing the field type to `longtext`.

Hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary to check up what type costs for the table and for a concrete field. As I understand it, if the configuration is applied after the table has been created, then changing the character type of the database does not affect the table and field settings. I changed the settings for the database type, the table and the specific field where I wrote the value from utf-8.
queries will look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `dbName`.`TableName` 
CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 ;
```

it was for the table. For field:

```
ALTER TABLE `TableName` 
CHANGE COLUMN `columname` `columname` type CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NOT NULL ;
```

also a Collation related error may occur when using functions and possibly in other cases. To fix, change the table field Collation to one that is compatible. Error example:

> Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='